# Setting a default queue for ActionMailer deliver_later?

Tags: actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-4.2

You can specify which queue to use when calling deliver_later in an ActionMailer by adding :queue as optional argument, e.g.:

`Notifier.welcome(User.first.id).deliver_later(queue: "low")`

Is there a way to do this in a general way, for all ActionMailers? To set the default ActionMailer queue?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Before Rails 5

Looking through Rails' [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ced687fe710b2f3d6cf0d0e978bdb531357299e4/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb) you can see that they already set the default queue name as '**mailers**'.

Still, if you want to change that default you can always override it by including the following code in an initialiser or loaded lib file:

```
class ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
  queue_as :default_mailer_queue
end
```

### Since Rails 5

Rails 5 allows you to set the default queue naming by simply configuring it.

E.g. add to you `application.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name = 'default_mailer_queue'
```

Comment: There will be a configuration option in Rails 5: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f5a131aaeaf0533e5f81461c2ad63474a865c19c#diff-97c5eb1c8630a41aec5c7b5453236d62

Comment: It doesn't seem to support setting a different queues for different mailers unfortunately. I guess the best way then is to use a monkey patch: `queue_as { mailer = self.arguments.first; mailer == "FooMailer" ? :foo : :bar }`.