# ActionMailer, Sneakers, deliver_later function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rabbitmq, sneakers

I have next code:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'sneakers'

# application.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sneakers

# application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
...
  def send_letter(params={})
    mail(params)
  ...
  end
end

# my_mailer_controller.rb
def send_my_mail
  ApplicationMailer.send_letter(params).deliver_later
end
```

rabbitmq-server is installed and started.
When I run 'send_my_mail' function I receive in Rails console message:

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: b2c66a30-70d1-4bba-a88e-d6260443347d) to Sneakers(mailers) with arguments: "ApplicationMailer", "send_letter", "deliver_now", ...
```

But when I run ActiveJob worker using terminal command:

```
WORKERS=ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SneakersAdapter::JobWrapper rake sneakers:run
```

nothing happens. Looks like the mailer listener with correct class name does not start so the letters are not sent. In Rabbitmq UI tracer I see record for message event:

```
Node:         rabbit@ubuntu-trusty-64
Connection:   127.0.0.1:35834 -> 127.0.0.1:5672
Virtual host: /
User:         guest
Channel:      1
Exchange:     sneakers
Routing keys: [<<"mailers">>]
Routed queues: []
Properties:   [{<<"priority">>,signedint,0},
               {<<"delivery_mode">>,signedint,2},
               {<<"content_type">>,longstr,<<"application/octet-stream">>}]
Payload: 
{"job_class":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","job_id":"7a58ab27-d110-4e8b-911b-fe821735e1b7","queue_name":"mailers","arguments":["ApplicationMailer","send_newsletter","deliver_now",...
```

What is the correct WORKER name for 'deliver_later' Active Job and Sneakers?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `ActionMailer` uses `mailers` queue as default queue to send emails. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245914/setting-a-default-queue-for-actionmailer-deliver-later)

Sneakers also using `mailers` queue to send emails by default. But there is no Worker for queue named `mailers`.

Possible approaches are:

1. Create a new worker for `mailers` queue and do all stuff manually
2. Explicitly define queue in `deliver_later` method as follows:

   ```
   ApplicationMailer.send_letter(params).deliver_later(queue: 'default')
   ```
3. Override default queue name for `ActionMailer` in `application.rb`

   ```
   config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name = 'default'
   ```

   And send the emails as as usual then:

   ```
   ApplicationMailer.send_letter(params).deliver_later
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is to elaborate the worker for mailers, as mentioned by retgoat.

Suppose you are delivering later using a specific queue (say, customMailQueue).
`ApplicationMailer.send_letter(params).deliver_later(queue: 'customMailQueue')`
The mail would be queued by sneakers in RabbitMQ.

For you to successfully send the queued message, we'll need to consume the message and then execute it.

```
class YourEmailWorker
    include Sneakers::Worker
    from_queue 'customMailQueue'
    def work(msg)
      job_data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(msg)
      ActiveJob::Base.execute job_data
      ack!
    end
  end
```

Remember, to put the custom Worker on `sneaker_worker_group.yml`

```
singleworkergroup:
  classes: YourEmailWorker
  workers: 1
```

And start the sneakers to start consuming and working on the queued emails.